# AndroidAlarmManager not executing

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to set an Alarm, which is called every minute. The AlarmService starts successful but when I try to finally setup the Alarm nothing happens.

logs:

```
I/AlarmService( 7423): Starting AlarmService...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/AlarmService( 7423): AlarmService started!
```

main.dart

```
  final int dailyAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(...);
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), dailyAlarmID,
      () {
    print("TESTING ALARM");
  });
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Try creating your anonymous function as a named function above the main method as pass it as arguement without calling it just as it is im the Alarm manager example. here https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager

Comment: I tried this, but I get the error in the IDE: The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore cannot be used

Comment: Did you try it without the parenthesis? Don't call the function.

Comment: I tried it in both variants. However, I fixed the problem, but still thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a long time I fixed the problem. You have to put your method, which is executed by the alarm manager, after the main-method.